# Removing part of a published topics path

Tags: ros, diagnostics, ros-kinetic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Say if im publishing diagnostic messages from a node using this;

```
nh.advertise<diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticArray>("diagnostics", 10);
```

In the case its from our IMU node, making the topic its publishing called /imu/diagnostics. Is there a way to remove the /imu prefix so that the aggregator doesn't get confused? Or should I be running diagnostics from a separate node or something?

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303850/removing-part-of-a-published-topics-path/) by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found my own solution.

When defining a publisher, if you're trying to publish to the top level you must add a '/' to the front of the path. For example;

```
nh.advertise<diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticArray>("/diagnostics", 10);
```

publishes to the topic;

```
/diagnostics
```

While

```
nh.advertise<diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticArray>("diagnostics", 10);
```

publishes to the

```
node_name/diagnostics
```

---

Originally posted by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) with karma: 17 on 2018-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-09-20**:
You're right, the [wiki Names](http://wiki.ros.org/Names) explains it with more details if you want.

**Comment by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on 2018-10-04**:
I guess I wasn't googling the right words, thanks for the link!